# jQuery array of products

Tags: jquery, json

I am trying to create an array of product SKU's which I can then pass onto a web service.

In a text area I type say `"123 456 789"` I then want to pick each item from the text box and pass it using JSON so the JSON shows:

```
"productcode" : "123", "productcode" : "456", "productcode" : "789"
```

How would I go about do this please?

I have tried

```
var json_data = JSON.stringify({
  productcode: $('#txtAddMultiProducts').val()
});
```

Which is returning `"productcode" : "123,456,789"`

Comment: If you type `123 456 789`, `$('#txtAddMultiProducts').val()` should give you  `123 456 789`, not `123,456,789`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the JavaScript `.split()` function to split the input by spaces and then construct your JSON according to the array you get in return.

```
var inputValue = $('#txtAddMultiProducts').val();
var values=inputValue.split(" "); 
// if the values are separated by commas, you can use `inputValue.split(",");`
```

This will give you an array similar to this -

```
[123,456,789]
```

Now, iterating over that array, you can construct your JSON object -

```
var finalObj = {}; // short-hand for "new Object()"
$.each(values,function(index,value){
  finalObj['productcode_'+index] = value;
});
```

You have to have unique indexes for your final JSON object otherwise each value will override the last.

This code should give you a result similar to this -

```
{'productcode_0':'123','productcode_1':'456','productcode_2':'789'}
```

Comment: so can i have it so that it only has productcode? without the index values?

Comment: var finalObj = {}; // short-hand for "new Object()"
$.each(values,function(index,value){
  finalObj['productcode'] = value;
});

I am guessing? (sorry i dont know how to format these comments!)

Comment: sorry, just read you comments properly! so i would need to have the index for each one.

Comment: Yes - if you need, at a later stage to pick out those individual values one by one, then you have to have some unique identifier (an index).